# Need one of two things. Scheduler to run EXE as end user or way to open browser silently

Tags: wcf, service, call, schedule

I have a webservice that takes the endusers username (not password) and returns a URL of a message that that user needs to see.   My problem is how to call this webservice and launch a browser to display the url. (if there is one to display)   They want to call this webservice multiple times daily.

I've tried running a script using a scheduler service but it runs as "System" and won't launch the browser window.   I can launch an Aspx page to call the web service but if there is no URL for that end user then I get a browser that flashes open then closed.  Not good for end users.

I'm open to suggestions on how I can make this happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the user the scheduled task runs as. check this page under [security options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851678.aspx)